# How can I set Angular 6 Material sidenav to open right to left from the right side of the screen

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular-material, angular6

This is the code example being used in angular Material for Sidenav. Im using this very same example on my page. However, I could find any instructions how to open the sidenav from left to right from the right side of the screen. Anybody knows how to ?

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" [(opened)]="opened" (opened)="events.push('open!')"
               (closed)="events.push('close!')">
    Sidenav content
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <p><mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="opened">sidenav.opened</mat-checkbox></p>
    <p><button mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">sidenav.toggle()</button></p>
    <p>Events:</p>
    <div class="example-events">
      <div *ngFor="let e of events">{{e}}</div>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: You have check css. Look for "left: some value px; "  value inside  <mat-sidenav-content> css. And then change it to "right: some value px;"

Comment: maybe you mean you couldn't find the instruction?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you look to the [API](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api) tab there is an input directive `position` for you to define.

> `position: 'start' | 'end'`
>
> The side that the drawer is attached to.

```
<mat-drawer-container class="example-container">
  <mat-drawer #sideNav mode="side" opened="true" position="end">
    Right drawer
  </mat-drawer>
  <mat-drawer-content>
    Main content
  </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-sidenav-positioning)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use input directive `position="end"` for opening from the right side in mat-drawer.

For instance:

```
<mat-drawer position="end">
```

https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview

Answer (score 0):

I have tried adding `position="end"` to make it work but it didn't.

For any lost desperate souls, try adding `style.position="absolute"` and set your `.sidenav` to have `left: calc(100% - 200px);`

Comment: Mb. put attribute position="end" into <mat-sidenav> tag instead of <mat-sidenav-container> ...?